# iMac 27" intermittently fails to reach login screen after Mountain Lion Upgrade

Tags: macos, imac, login-items, login-screen

I have recently upgraded to Mountain Lion from Snow leopard and now the system will not always go to the login screen. (iMac 27" circa 2010 standard as it came from Apple no upgrades)

I have tried disconnecting all devices and uninstalling all non essential software.

To get the login screen I have to hard switch of the machine off then after 20 30 seconds turn it back on it sometimes goes to the login screen.

If I start in safe mode then reboot it always goes to the login screen.

Comment: Not good, not good...could it be your boot track is damaged, open console and look for disk I/O errors

Comment: Used the disk utility and the verify and repair both come up saying OK nothing to repair.

Comment: Try running the cmd-r during boot to bring up the repair services, then follow the instructions.